# generate dynamic background path in vuejs with tailwind

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm having problems generating a dynamic background path in vuejs and tailwind. How can I realize that?

```
<div :class="bg-[url(`{~@/assets/hg/hg_${bgNum}.webp}`)]">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it works the way you tried it. To generate a dynamic background image I would propose a slightly different approach.

You can use Vue.js's `:style` directive to bind inline styles to a DOM element. This allows for dynamic style properties based on your component's data.

If you need additional styling with tailwind you can create a custom css class and `@apply` Tailwind Utilities to it.

```js
<template>
  <div :style="bgStyle">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      bgNum: 1  // or whatever your dynamic value is
    }
  },
  computed: {
    bgStyle() {
      return {
        backgroundImage: `url('./hg/hg_${this.bgNum}.webp')`
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
/* If you need to apply TailwindCSS utilities */
.bg-custom {
  @apply bg-cover bg-center;
}
</style>
```

At the [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) you can see in the console that the browser tries to fetch the correct image.

Comment: @bluelemonade and? Did it work?

Comment: sorry, I deleted the comment:

i switched from <div id="content-grid" class=" bg-bgcolor h-full m-auto bg-center bg-[url('~@/assets/hg/hg_1.webp')] bg-no-repeat bg-cover"> 
to
<div id="content-grid" :style="bgStyle()" class=" bg-bgcolor h-full m-auto bg-center bg-no-repeat bg-cover">

const bgStyle = () => {
      let bg = `background-image: url('~@/assets/hg/hg_${bgNum}.webp');`
     console.log(bg, bgNum);
      return bg;
    }

in chrome I see: style="background-image: url(&quot;~@/assets/hg/hg_3.webp&quot;);
but no image

Comment: I edited my answer, try it now. The function now returns an object additionaly I quoted the image path. At the vuejs playground it tries to fetch the image ( as you can see in the console ) so it should work if the image exists

Comment: style="background-image: url(&quot;~@/assets/hg/hg_3.webp&quot;);"
 the image exists in this path, but didn't show

Comment: loaded from the public path it works: backgroundImage: `url('./hg/hg_${bgNum}.webp')`

Comment: great I edited  my answer